# Lax/colax monoidal adjunction in terms of unit and counit

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, monoidal-categories

Following nLab's [page on monoidal adjunctions](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+adjunction), it seems there is a bunch of options for an adjunction to become "monoidal" in some sense.

I think that the one called **monoidal adjunction** in the nLab page is usually presented as an adjunction in which the unit and counit are monoidal natural transformations. Similarly, the one called **opmonoidal adjunction** is usually presented as an adjunction in which the unit and counit are opmonoidal natural transformations.

I wonder if there is a similar characterisation for **lax/colax monoidal adjunction** in terms of its unit and counit?